# Parsing DateTime with this custom format

Tags: java, datetime

I am trying to parse a Date like this:

THU 04/04 - 1PM PST

I have tried different patterns, and currently I have this one:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatoFechaHora = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd/MM - ha z");
Date daa=formatoFechaHora.parse("THU 04/04 - 1PM PST");
```

This throws an exception:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu 02/07 - 1PM PST" (at
>   offset 0)

What is the right pattern to parse this?

Comment: The exception message doesn't match with the code you show. You say you parse "THU 04/04 - 1PM PST", and the exception says you parse "2013/02/07 - 1PM PST". Change your question: we don't even know what you really want to parse, and with which pattern you're trying to do it.

Comment: sorry I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your **should** be   `EEE dd/MM - ha z`

note that `EEE` is for the **day** `THU` and `yyyy` is for **year** like 2013.

**EDIT**:
you probably need to set your Locale to ENGLISH explicitly.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatoFechaHora = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd/MM - ha z", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: Thanx, but I edited my question because I made a mistake. The pattern still doesn't work!

Comment: @Perroloco check my edit, you need to set your LOCALE to ENGLISh

Answer (score 2):

Always consult the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) if you're not familiar with `DateFormat` patterns. You need

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd/MM - ha z", Locale.ENGLISH)
```

Also, your default `Locale` may not be matching your day or timezone fields.

Comment: thanx, I made a mistake at the question. Edited it now. I tried with your pattern and it still doesnt work...

Comment: You were right, thank you. I accepted PremGenError's answer because he answered first, upvote for you ;)